# RDFDataMgr write does not work with milion objects

Tags: java, jena

I have java application which works with jena tdb. I have 3 milion objects in the db and when i want to make export on jena i am having problems.

For export i tried with:

```
RDFDataMgr.write(file, model, Lang.RDFXML);
```

and also with:

```
RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter("RDF/XML");
writer.setProperty("allowBadURIs", true);
writer.setProperty("relativeURIs", "");
writer.setProperty("tab", "2");
writer.setProperty("showXmlDeclaration", "true");
writer.write(model, file, null);
```

But non of this worked. So my question is how can i fix this problem?

Comment: what means *"not worked"*? can you show more of the code, in particular the type of the `model`? Note, TDB also provides CLI tools

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i saw now what cause the problem.
It is: Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: ok, so you know how to fix it?

Comment: if increasing the heap space isn't possible, switching to a stream based format like `N-TRIPLES` would indeed avoid the problem of having the whole XML tree in-memory first.

Comment: I am searching now for increasing java heap space..

Comment: I changed the Lang to Lang.NTRIPLES and the model is exported but not in the way i want. I want to be exported like RDF/XML. The only solution is to increase the java heap space and to increase RAM?

Comment: Well, of course it's not RDFXML if you change to NTRIPLES. The [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html) explains all formats plus which of them allow for stream based writing. Besides increasing the heap which shouldn't be that difficult you could try `RDFXML_PLAIN` - not sure whether this would avoid memory issues. If not, just increase the heap space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184521/discussion-between-bambus-and-aksw).

Comment: (chat not recorded here)
Use `RDFFormat.RDFXML_PLAIN`.

Comment: Sorry for late response! I successfully exported my model :D with second solution RDFWriter and increasing Java Heap Space