# RDFWriter write takes so much time

Tags: java, jena

I have Java app with Jena TDB. I want to make export on the database which has over 3 million objects.

For exporting i have increased Java heap space and i am using:

```
  RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter("RDF/XML");
  writer.setProperty("allowBadURIs", true);
  writer.setProperty("relativeURIs", ""); 
  writer.setProperty("tab", "0"); 
  writer.setProperty("showXmlDeclaration", "true");
  writer.setProperty("xmlbase", JENAXMLBASE);
  fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
  writer.write(writableModel, fis, null);
```

It works fine but the function takes so much time. I can see that file is created and i can open the exported file but the function continues to work.

My question is how can i reduce the execution time and to stop the function when the file is created and the objects are exported if it is possible?

Comment: See also same code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555000/rdfdatamgr-write-does-not-work-with-milion-objects

Comment: It is my question. The code is the same but the question is different

Answer (score 1):

"RDF/XML" is pretty-printed output and can be expensive, depending on the data.

You can also try using a buffered output stream.

Or try different RDFWriter settings, especially the rules:  https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html#advanced-rdfxml-output

Comment: I know that RDF/XML is expensive and also i saw that documentation and i used the Faster RDF/XML I/O but i noticed that when the file is created and it comes to 1.5 GB for example it takes (30-50 minutes for 3 million objects and all the objects are inside the file so the export is finished) but the function continues to work and it takes 30 more minutes to finish which are unnecessary. My question is can i stop the function when the file is created (export is finished) and to avoid the other 30 minutes.

Comment: The code above is not using the faster RDFXML writer. The "RDF/XML" setting model.write is RDFFormat.RDFXML_ABBREV, the expensive pretty printer.  Creating a file is not the same as finishing writing. The file is created by `FileOutputStream` (at which point it is empty).

Comment: RDFWriter fasterWriter = m.getWriter("RDF/XML");
fasterWriter.setProperty("allowBadURIs","true");
fasterWriter.setProperty("relativeURIs","");
fasterWriter.setProperty("tab","0");

as i can see from the link this is Faster RDF/XML.
I know that file is created by FileOutputStream yes the file is empty but after 30 min is full with the objects and i want to stop there. I can open the file and i can see the object, and i want function to stop there and not to continue to work for 30 more minutes and to not change anything in the file.

Comment: If you think about RDFXML_PLAIN i think that i am using Plain because documentation says that "RDF/XML" = RDFXML_PLAIN and if i use Lang.RDFXML = RDF/XML, pretty printed

Comment: Then the documentation is out of date - where exactly?  Does the .write call return? That it takes along time is usually due to the shape of the data.